# How to capture Android Web Browser performance metrics?

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing

I have an ask for capturing performance metrics from a mobile web browser called Silk.

My device is an Android device so I can `ADB` to it. Is there a way I can capture a performance metrics from an Logcat or any type of logs?

The types of performance metrics I am trying to capture are like: Frame Drops, Latency, Time To First Frame, Error Rate etc...

An example scenario is like this: Go to website X, then navigate to page Y and capture the latency, time it took to render the frame.

Another example is: While on the web page, scroll Up/Down and capture the frame drops, time it took for scrolling etc...

Comment: Does this help you? https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#manual-network

Comment: Have you seen: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/remote-debugging.html and https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Please be specific about your android device.
Secondly if you are trying to measure such things what you are actually trying to look at is performance of the browser in terms of HTML and CSS rendering.
Also for the second part of question when you ask about scrolling it basically depends on your Android Phone RAM and not the browser as the browser would hang or crash otherwise.
There would be no way to measure the latency with the phone in hand so you should rather use a slow motion capturing device, as if you try using the phone to measure the latency it has to be a program which has to share the same processor as the web browser itself and therefore cannot give the correct performance matrix.
This is also the way companies do in order to test their benchmarks in terms of performance.